# Unique Code Validation in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Our company run a lot of responsive online promotions, such as this: http://www.cokegolf.com.au/

We were wondering if [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) would support validation of a unique code against a database.  The database of codes can be anywhere from 10,0000 to 50,000.  The form would need to prevent submission when an invalid code is used.

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) does not currently support database lookups.  However, we are actively working on a feature called Dynamic Webhooks that would provide this exact functionality.  You would still have to maintain the database of codes yourself (possibly just a Google spreadsheet) but would be able to have the form perform custom validation of codes against this database using a very simple RESTful JSON endpoint.

Please comment and upvote this feature if it is something you are interested in!

https://trello.com/c/sgDIKA7o/143-dynamic-webhooks